# moving from synchronous API to async API

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to move from using a synchronous API to async API:

```
    void Client()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        int numAttempts = SendWithRetries();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Logging.Log(LoggingLevel.Info, string.Format("time taken {0} ", numEvents, partitionId, stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString()));

    }

    private int SendWithRetries(int numRetries = 3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= numRetries; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                API();
                return i;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (i == numRetries)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Now to move to async API, I gather from internet that I need to replace API with

```
await APIAsync()
```

I am a little confused on this. When I add await, it would force the main thread to wait for completion of APIAsync How is that different from the synchronous call?

What if I do the following change and continue calling API() within SendWithRetries method:

```
void Client()
    {
        Task newTask =
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();
                int numAttempts = SendWithRetries();
                stopWatch.Stop();
                Logging.Log(LoggingLevel.Info, string.Format("### time taken {0} ", numEvents, partitionId, stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString()));
            });

        newTask.Wait();
    }
```

Why is using the async method with await better than the above approach?

Also, whats wrong with the following:

```
private int SendWithRetries(int numRetries = 3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= numRetries; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                APIAsync();
                return i;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (i == numRetries)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Using `await` allows the main thread to continue processing outside of you `SendWithRetries` and only returning when a value is available. The `Task.Run` means you now have two threads.

Answer (score 2):

> How is that different from the synchronous call?

Asynchronous code doesn't block the calling thread.

> Why is using the async method with await better than the above approach?

That approach moves the blocking to a thread pool thread (`Task.Run`). Asynchronous code doesn't block a thread pool thread.

> Also, whats wrong with the following

Since the code ignores the returned `Task`, the code can never know when the API call completes, or whether it had an error.

More information:

- [Async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)
- [Async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword allows the application to wait without becoming non-responsive. The user will be able to continue interacting with the application, while the awaited operation is running in the background. When the operation completes, the code after the await will execute, by default in the UI thread.

You may need to restrict the user from certain interactions for the duration of the awaited operation. Some buttons or menu options may better become disabled, so that the user cannot initiate multiple asynchronous operations, and cause resources starvation or other problems.